# Do you have an accordion menu for Aurelia UI Framework

Tags: aurelia-ui-framework

On [page](https://adarshpastakia.github.io/aurelia-ui-framework/#/menus)

Looking at the basic sidebar menu could you make the headers Action/Options a clickable accordion?

Comment: It cannot be done out of the box, but I think that with little tweaking, it should not be that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the new V4 it can be done.
https://adarshpastakia.github.io/auf-demo-v4/
look at the main menu of the site.